Power selector for 12V car battery and Li-Ion
I am currently using the following power selector circuit (based on this Microchip app note) to switch between a 5V (5V5A) supply and a Li-Ion 3.7V battery (VBAT). This feeds the VIN node, which in turn is connected to a 3V3 buck converter.

However, I have to modify the topology to use a 12V supply instead of the 5V. As far as I can see, this shouldn't be a problem:

When the 12V is present, Vgs will be equal to the diode's voltage drop and the P-MOSFET will not conduct. VIN will be 12V minus the diode's voltage drop.
When 12V are not present, R24 will pull down the P-MOSFET's gate, Vgs will be -VBAT and the P-MOSFET will conduct. VIN will be approximately equal to VBAT.

My question is the following: given that the 12V will be coming from a diesel motor's battery, I am wondering if this might introduce other considerations into the design of the switch or the component selection?. As a note, I have also integrated a reverse polarity protection circuit for the 12V input (like the one shown here).

Sounds to me like you're not making a product for mass production, but a gadeget for yourself. Two different situations! I would add some rudimentary EMC-protection.
As beefy a TVS as you can spare room for, most likely, and some LC filters on the input will at least protect somewhat.
Littelfuse has an app note about choosing tvs for automotive that could be looked at:
https://web.archive.org/web/20200823170828/https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/application_notes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_automotive_circuit_protection_using_automotive_tvs_diodes_application_note.pdf.pdf

Thanks! Actually I will be making a couple hundred of these devices... Any literature on sizing of the LC filter that you might have?

Then you should consider setting up an EMC test plan and contacting a test lab.
LC filter sizing would depend on typical frequencies in the system, both upstream and downstream. I don't know your application nor the automotive environment to give any more specific
